# Using equal sign for HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST not working

Tags: java-8, resttemplate, bad-request, spring-web, http-status

I'm just wondering why using **==** to check equality of **HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST** is not working:

```
HttpStatus httpStatusCode ...;
if (httpStatusCode == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) {}
```

I got it working by using **equals** method:

```
if (httpStatusCode.equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {}
```

But, **HttpStatus.OK** is working as in:

```
if (httpStatusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {}
```

I discovered it when I had this code:

```
if (httpStatusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
...
} else if (httpStatusCode == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST ) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Assumming **httpStatusCode** is **HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST**, instead of going through **else if** block, it went to **else** block. But, when I changed **==** to **.equals()**, it worked.

I'm using **Spring Web 4.3.6.RELEASE**. Is there any explanation on this? Thank you

Comment: It shouldnt make any difference since `HttpStatus` is an enum, there should only be one instance, so reference equality should be fine.

Comment: I have said, it didn't work using == but .equals().

Answer (score 2):

Use **value()** method:

```
httpStatusCode.value() == HttpStatus.OK.value()
```

If you will look inside the `HttpStatus.java` file, you can see it is an `enum` and it has a value method which return an int value of the HttpStatus, so you can use it to compare your Status codes. 
And .equals works as it checks the enums value as == checks reference.